# Combine loop values from different SOAP methods

Tags: php, loops, soap

I'm getting data from different SOAP methods. For an example:

```
$wsdl = 'the_url_of_wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$parameters = array(all_the_parameters_inside);
$values = $client->the_method($parameters);
$xml = $values->the_methodResult->any; 
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

$wsdl2 = 'the_url2_of_wsdl';
$client2 = new SoapClient($wsdl2); 
$parameters2 = array(all_the_parameters_inside);
$values2 = $client->the_method2($parameters2);
$xml2 = $values2->the_method2Result->any; 
$sxml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);

$wsdl3 = 'the_url3_of_wsdl';
$client3 = new SoapClient($wsdl3); 
$parameters3 = array(all_the_parameters_inside);
$values3 = $client->the_method3($parameters3);
$xml3 = $values3->the_method3Result->any; 
$sxml3 = simplexml_load_string($xml3);
```

If I print_r $sxml, $sxml2 and $sxml3, inside I can get any data, lets say

`echo $sxml->name;` , `echo $sxml2->id;` and `echo $sxml3->description;`.

The tricky part is these values are from different methods, so how can I combine them in loops in a same HTML structure, so to be like this:

```
<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value from the second method</div>
   <div class="description">the value from the third method</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value from the second method</div>
   <div class="description">the value from the third method</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value from the second method</div>
   <div class="description">the value from the third method</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Here's extended example what I'm trying to achieve. An example of two methods.

print_r(sxml) from the first soap method shows a structure like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [NewDataSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [HotelFacility] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [HotelId] => 1
                            [HotelCode] => TEST
                            [FacNo] => 6
                            [FacName] => test (bank)
                            [OriginalName] => 
                            [IsPriced] => No
                            [MediaID] => 1
                            [Note] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [UseinWebFilter] => true
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [HotelId] => 1
                            [HotelCode] => TEST2
                            [FacNo] => 12
                            [FacName] => test center
                            [OriginalName] => Test Center
                            [IsPriced] => No
                            [MediaID] => 1
                            [Note] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [UseinWebFilter] => true
                        ) //and the list continues...
```

print_r(sxml2) from the second soap method shows a structure like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [NewDataSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [HotelPresentation] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [RecId] => 5
                            [HotelId] => 14
                            [HotelCode] => test hotel
                            [PresText] => "the description".
                            [TextType] => HTML
                            [TextCategory] => GENERAL
                            [MediaID] => 4
                            [CrtDate] => 2016-01-06T15:34:00+02:00
                            [ChgDate] => 2016-01-06T15:34:00+02:00
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [RecId] => 3
                            [HotelId] => 4
                            [HotelCode] => test hotel2
                            [PresText] => //and the list continues....
```

How do I merge these two arrays and get the result, let's say I want to make a html structure like this:

```
<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value facName from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value hotelCode from the second method</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value facName from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value hotelCode from the second method</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
   <div class="name">the value facName from the first method</div>
   <div class="id">the value hotelCode from the second method</div>
</div>
```

The HTML article will display dynamically depends how many results are in SOAP methods.

Comment: array($wsdl,$wsdl2,$wsdl3); and foreach for this array

Comment: Hi, can you please show an example? It's not gonna be that simple to put the wsdl's inside an array. Every method has a different parameters inside, so I cannot just use one foreach loop for all like that.

Comment: Only this the_url3_of_wsdl value is change for every record?

Comment: The wsdl url's are different. Inside the methods are different too. The question is how to combine the values inside a loop and make the html structure that I've wrote in the thread? Right now I can get the data from separate loops and in a separate values, but I cannot set them inside a proper HTML structure. If it was a database, that will be easy. Creating one loop and get the all the details from one table, but with SOAP is more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$sxml1 = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
$sxml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);

$facilities = $sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility;
$presentations = $sxml2->NewDataSet->HotelPresentation;

foreach ($facilities as $i => $facility) {
    echo '<div class="article">';
    echo '<div class="name">'. $facility->FacName .'</div>';
    echo '<div class="id">'. $presentations[$i]->HotelCode .'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Assuming, of course, that HotelFacility and HotelPresentation array elements can be linked together like this (by their index position). It's kind of hard to establish the relationship between the two based on your explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not working. The loop produces three article elements, not dynamic results.

Comment: Wasn't this what you wanted to achieve? Please clarify the description of your issue and elaborate on what kind of "dynamic result" you're trying to get.

Comment: Hi, Sergey. I've edited my main post. I hope it's more understandable what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how I missed the whole code example. The id value is not working. I'm getting proper results from the $facility->FacName, but not from $presentations[$i]->hotelCode. I'm getting the right number of the article html, but without id inside...I spoke too soon, Sergey. If I set separate loops just for a test with $facilities and $presentations I'm getting all the needed values, but it doesn't work when it's inside the loop from your code. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I've just checked other posts. Index works with two arrays that will act like $key and $value. Mine case is different. I want specific values from different methods to be displayed in a one big loop.

Comment: It should be "HotelCode", not "hotelCode", sorry. I've made an edit to my answer.

Comment: I've tried that either, but the id doesn't display anything.

Comment: Are you sure your code looks exactly as entered above? What happens if you try to var_dump the $presentations? What happens if you try to var_dump the $sxml2? The code must be working as is, if the data structures look exactly like those samples you've posted.

Comment: The only difference is $sxml1 is $sxml11 and $sxml2 is $sxml12 in my code, but every time I change that when I try to test. I've just checked the var_dump($presentations)  and var_dump($sxml2) in my code var_dump($sxml12) and I'm receiving bunch of results inside for the both arrays

Comment: var_dump($presentations) shows results that starts from object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (9) { and after that the keys and the values like: RecId => 5, HotelId => 14, HotelCode => name_of_the_hotel and var_dump($sxml2) or in my code var_dump($sxml12) shows: object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) { and after that NewDataSet and nesting again with HotelPresentation and after that the same values like var_dump($presentations).

Comment: By the way, I can see you saw the other thread, just wanted to open and post more simple thread with idea to be more understandable, but I'm still struggling my head... unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like there's only one element in HotelPresentation, which is a SimpleXMLElement object and not an array. Your example in the question is therefore invalid (because there it's an array), and the suggested code won't work.

Comment: So, this is more difficult than I thought... If I'm able to paste the full code somewhere, just to show you what it looks like...also as I previously wrote, this won't be the full code, 'cos I have to use more than two methods and I'm pretty much in a dead end now...

Comment: Hi, Sergey. Finally a solution for the problem! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440353/join-data-from-different-soap-methods/35441179