# Join data from different SOAP methods

Tags: php, loops, join, soap

I'm getting data from a couple of SOAP methods. With simplexml_load_string() I can get the specific data and with foreach loop I can display the values from that method.

Here's a part of my code for two methods results:

```
foreach($sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility as $item) {   
    echo '<div class="hotel">'; 
    echo '<div class="name">' . $item->FacName . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
foreach($sxml2->NewDataSet->HotelPresentation as $item) {   
    echo '<div class="hotel">'; 
    echo '<div class="desc">' . $item->PresText . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

How can I join these values into a one main hotel div HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="hotel">
   <div class="name">the_value_from_the_first_method</div>
   <div class="desc">the_value_from_the_second_method</div>
</div>

<div class="hotel">
   <div class="name">the_value_from_the_first_method</div>
   <div class="desc">the_value_from_the_second_method</div>
</div>

<div class="hotel">
   <div class="name">the_value_from_the_first_method</div>
   <div class="desc">the_value_from_the_second_method</div>
</div>...
```

Notice: The number of divs will display dynamically as a result from a SOAP method, so the result has to be produced from foreach loop.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418407/combine-loop-values-from-different-soap-methods/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine values from separate `simpleXMLelement` objects (solution with `array_map` function):

```
$sxml1 = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
$sxml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);

$hotelFac = $hotelPres = [];
foreach($sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility as $item) {
    $hotelFac[] = '<div class="hotel"><div class="name">' . $item->FacName . '</div>';
}
foreach($sxml2->NewDataSet->HotelPresentation as $item) {
    $hotelPres[] = '<div class="desc">' . $item->PresText . '</div></div>';
}

$result = array_map(function($name, $desc){
    return $name . $desc;
}, $hotelFac, $hotelPres);

echo implode('', $result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Hi, Roman. I've tried your solution, but I'm receiving an error:   **Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array** and it's not display anything.

Comment: Is not $sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility` an array of objects? What gives `var_dump(gettype($sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility));` ?

Comment: it gives: `string(6) "object" `

Comment: could you also show me `var_dump(get_class($sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility));` ? thanks

Comment: It doesn't display anything with that function.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking that you were working with arrays. But there are objects. Ok, and the last step: show `var_dump(get_object_vars($sxml1->NewDataSet->HotelFacility));`

Comment: `array(9) { ["HotelId"]=> string(1) "1" ["HotelCode"]=> string(4) "TEST" ["FacNo"]=> string(1) "6" ["FacName"]=> string(10) "ATM (Bank)" ["OriginalName"]=> string(10) "ATM (Bank)" ["IsPriced"]=> string(2) "No" ["MediaID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Note"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (0) { } ["UseinWebFilter"]=> string(4) "true" } `

Comment: was it full output? cause I see `array(9)`, it's really an array or it's just part of output(nested array)?

Comment: Yes, that's full output. With simplexml_load_string() I'm converting the simplexml object into array, but I don't know why array_map() displays an error.

Comment: try to convert it in such way: `$simple = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
$arr = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);`. After converting, try my update with string keys

Comment: I've just tried your new solution, changed the names, on your answer I've changed that too, but I'm receiving the same error again: **Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array**

Comment: that means that the previous SimpleXMLElement conversion to array was not successful. Try to convert it as in the following post: http://www.binarytides.com/convert-simplexml-object-to-array-in-php/, then rename the second and the third arguments in my solution due to the new obtained arrays

Comment: I've just read the post from the link. I'm afraid I didn't understand the details related with the **function xml2array** I'm kind a lost there. So, this is another approach and I guess I have to go back and learn the different  decoding with json...too heavy for my head at the moment...

Comment: :) I understand you. I could resolve your issue if I had your initial full xml file content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103646/discussion-between-user2519032-and-romanperekhrest).